# client does not receive all messages if server sends messages too quickly with pickle python

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

My client side cannot recv the two messages if the sender sends too quickly.

sender.py

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)


sock.bind(('', int(port)))
sock.listen(1)

conn, addr = sock.accept()
#conn.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

# sends message 1 and message 2
conn.send(pickle.dumps(message1))
#time.sleep(1)
conn.send(pickle.dumps(message2))
```

Where both message 1 and message 2 are pickled objects.

client.py

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((ip,int(port)))

message1 = pickle.loads(sock.recv(1024))

print(message1)

message2 = pickle.loads(sock.recv(1024))
```

When i run this code as it is, i am able to print out message1 but i am unable to receive message2 from the sender. The socket blocks at message2.

Also, if i uncomment time.sleep(1) in my sender side code, i am able to receive both messages just fine. Not sure what the problem is. I tried to flush my TCP buffer everytime by setting TCP_NODELAY but that didnt work. Not sure what is actually happening ? How would i ensure that i receive the two messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes that each `send` on the server side will match a `recv` on the client side. But, TCP is byte stream and not a message based protocol. This means that it is likely that your first `recv` will already contain data from the second `send` which might be simply discarded by `pickle.loads` as junk after the pickled data. The second `recv` will only receive the remaining data (or just block since all data where already received) so `pickle.loads` will fail.

The common way to deal with this situation is to construct a message protocol on top of the TCP byte stream. This can for example be done by prefixing each message with a fixed-length size (for example as 4 byte uint using `struct.pack('L',...)`) when sending and for reading first read the fixed-length size value and then read the message with the given size.

Comment: is there any way to process this on the client side instead of the server side? For example maybe the client could split the bytes before calling pickle ?

Comment: @calveeen: In order to split before calling `pickle.loads` the client would need to know where to split first and I don't see any way how to figure this out using the pickle module. Another way would be to just let `loads` extract the pickled data and then care about the data not processed by `loads`. Only, `loads` silently ignores any data after the pickled data and provides no way to find out where the unpickled data have ended. So I don't see an easy way to do this on the client side only.